# cant execute buildtool jar file to extract apks from abb file

Tags: java, android, react-native, apk, bundletool

when I typing in this :

```
C:\Users\Ora Ora\Desktop\Dev\React\Native\Abb to APk>>java -jar bundletool-all-1.4.0.jar //..rest of args
```

I get thsi error :

> > '-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> > operable program or batch file.
> > but when I type in
> > when I typing in this :

```
C:\Users\Ora Ora\Desktop\Dev\React\Native\Abb to APk>>$ java -jar bundletool-all-1.4.0.jar //..rest of args
```

I gues it works but I'm  getting this error :

> > [BT:1.4.0] Error: null
> > java.lang.NullPointerException
> > at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.SignerConfig.lambda$extractFromKeystore$0(SignerConfig.java:109)
> > at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
> > at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.SignerConfig.extractFromKeystore(SignerConfig.java:106)
> > at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildApksCommand.populateSigningConfigurationFromFlags(BuildApksCommand.java:1059)
> > at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildApksCommand.fromFlags(BuildApksCommand.java:593)
> > at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildApksCommand.fromFlags(BuildApksCommand.java:559)
> > at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:75)
> > at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:47)

here is the full command :

```
java -jar bundletool-all-1.4.0.jar build-apks --bundle="C:\Users\Ora Ora\Desktop\Dev\React\Native\Abb to APk\app-release.aab" --output="C:\Users\Ora Ora\Desktop\Dev\React\Native\Abb to APk\apks.apks" --ks="C:\Users\Ora Ora\Desktop\Dev\React\Native\DistributionApp\android\app\my-upload-key.keystore" --ks-key-alias=my-key-alias
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/google/bundletool/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/model/SignerConfig.java#L109) (bundletool is open-source), it looks like you're running a Java environment that does not provide a console for you to enter the password.

I recall this is an issue on Windows platforms and I don't know an immediate workaround to enter the password on the command line.

However, you can provide the password in different ways, e.g. passing the `--ks-pass` flag. From bundletool's help command:

> --ks-pass: (Optional) Password of the keystore to use to sign the generated
> APKs. If provided, must be prefixed with either 'pass:' (if the password
> is passed in clear text, e.g. 'pass:qwerty') or 'file:' (if the password
> is the first line of a file, e.g. 'file:/tmp/myPassword.txt'). If this
> flag is not set, the password will be requested on the prompt.

Same for `--key-pass` in case the password of the key is different from the password from the keystore.

> --key-pass: (Optional) Password of the key in the keystore to use to sign
> the generated APKs. If provided, must be prefixed with either 'pass:'
> (if the password is passed in clear text, e.g. 'pass:qwerty') or 'file:'
> (if the password is the first line of a file, e.g. 'file:
> /tmp/myPassword.txt'). If this flag is not set, the keystore password
> will be tried. If that fails, the password will be requested on the
> prompt.